# Can an Object Definition's ID be obtained programmatically?

Tags: api, soap-api, salesforce-id, related-list, describesobject

I've noticed that SF related lists are anchored (#) by a concatenation of the current record's Id, an underscore, the Id of the related list's object definition, and then "_target" (e.g. #a4Ve00000009CGU_00Ne0000000FKYu_target).

I'm building an app that generates links to SF records and I'd prefer to add to the generated links an anchor to a specific related list, but I can't find a way to get the object definition's id. describeSObject doesn't seem to get it done (unless I'm missing something).

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The related list is not a separate object but rather a property of the lookup field that is driving that list. If you go to that fields definition under setup you can see that the url includes "00Ne0000000FKYu".

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to programmatically determine the ID of a custom field.

If you were building this for one org you could screen-scrape the setup pages to get all the IDs of your custom fields but for an app this is probably impossible.